# How do I serialize the object I am passing as a parameter from page to page in a Windows Store App

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, windows-8, xml-serialization

I am working on a Windows Store app and I am having an issue serializing my DTO classes back to the xml file that I was able to deserialize. After data-binding and changing some data I can't figure out how to serialize the DTO classes so that those changes can be there when I deserialize again. What I'm doing is after logging into my app I also pass my `Data` object to be used in the next page, the `ItemsListView` page. This is how I'm passing the object:

```
Dim oData As Data
oData = Await FileHelper.DeserializeXml()
Me.Frame.Navigate(GetType(ItemsListView),oData)
```

In my `ItemsListView` page I then bind my object to the `DataContext` to be able to view the data like this:

```
    Protected Overrides Sub LoadState(navigationParameter As Object, pageState As Dictionary(Of String, Object))

      Dim oData As Data = navigationParameter

      pageTitle.DataContext = oData.Field

      Me.DefaultViewModel("Items") = oData.ListRoot

    End Sub
```

I also then have another page in which I pass the item clicked object and bind that data to the next page, this is that code:

```
    Private Sub ItemView_ItemClick(sender As Object, e As ItemClickEventArgs) Handles itemGridView.ItemClick

    If e.ClickedItem IsNot Nothing Then
        Me.Frame.Navigate(GetType(RecordAddEditView), e.ClickedItem)
    End If

End Sub
```

There are more pages but I think this should suffice to get an idea of what my app is doing. So after passing all the objects to the next page and modifying the data on those pages, how can I serialize my `Data` object so that all the data from all the pages can be serialized? Should I be doing that in my GetDataForSerialization() method, for example making a call to the oData object in my LoginPage? It's probably something very simple just can't seem to figure it out after a few days. Any code suggestions appreciated.

Here is how I'm doing my serialization:

```
    Public Shared Async Function SerializeXml() As Task

    Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(Data))
    Dim nameSpaces As XmlSerializerNamespaces = New XmlSerializerNamespaces()
    Dim mStream As New MemoryStream()
    Dim result As Byte()
    Dim dataToSerialize As Data = GetDataForSerialization()

    ' Creates empty namespaces
    nameSpaces.Add(String.Empty, String.Empty)

    ' Serializes the objects
    serializer.Serialize(mStream, dataToSerialize, nameSpaces)

    ' Writes bytes to stream
    result = mStream.ToArray()

End Function

Private Shared Function GetDataForSerialization() As Data

    ' What to do here to get all the data from my Data class so that I can serialize it

End Function
```

Comment: I think you mean DTO, not POCO :)

Comment: So you are successful at serializing a `Data` object correct?  You just need to know how to get the `Data` object in the first place?

Comment: If I serialize my Data object I only get the root xml element tag and my Data root tag with nothing else

Comment: No worries.  You're by no means the first person I've heard using POCO to mean a data object.  I've never fully understood what the correct meaning for POCO is.  Perhaps EVERYONE is misusing the term :)

Comment: As your question stands, it's very difficult to help you because it's not clear how you are storing/referencing the `Data` object.  Your question shows a lot of examples related to serialization, but it doesn't seem like that's actually what your core question is about.  You'll need to show us what you are doing with the incoming DTO and how you are binding to it.  Then it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Well I have a login page that passes the deserialized xml to the next page like this `Me.Frame.Navigate(GetType(ItemsListView, oData)`. The `oData` has the deserialized xml data, which I then use on my `ItemsListView` page to data bind. Should I just try and call that `oData`?

Comment: I have edited the question and content

Comment: Yes, that's much more clear.  Unfortunately, I'm not at all familiar with web site programming in .NET, so I can't help you further :(